# Plugging 2 screens into a laptop

Tags: laptop, video, vga, splitter

My laptop has only one VGA port, so I was wondering if I can just buy a "Y-cable" and plug in 2 screens?

My graphic card is GeForce GT 640M LE.

PS: I want to extend my screens, not duplicate them.

Answer (score 2):

Default VGA only supports a single monitor. The monitor tells the system via the VGA cable what its dimensions and supported resolutions are, and the system then sends the correct data in response.

A simple passive Y adapter would not support an extended-desktop setup.

There are devices that actively communicate the necessary information to a system allowing it to send the data to fill two monitors over a VGA connector. However, as a rule, these active adapters cost quite a bit: http://www.xbitlabs.com/news/mobile/display/20051108205755.html

Answer (score 1):

Music2myear is correct, you would not be able to use a Y adapter.

An alternative solution would be to use a USB to VGA/DVI/etc [adapter](http://www.newegg.com/USB-Display-Adapters/SubCategory/ID-3046).

Comment: can this adapter also send sound information if I were to connect the USB port of my laptop to a HDMI TV ?